# explode JSON output to columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize

I have an excel file with JSON output in the following form:

{"text1":"1","text2":"1","text3":"0"}

I'd like to convert this to the following tabular format

| Text 1 | Text2 | Text 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

I've tried using json_normalize() but the response is stored in object type and it doesn't work

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It will be an object datatype as your input is

```
a ={"text1":"1","text2":"1","text3":"0"}
```

and not this

```
a ={"text1":1,"text2":1,"text3":0}
```

```
pd.json_normalize(a).astype(int)
```

should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

To convert that JSON output to a pandas Dataframe simply wrap it with the pandas DataFrame() as so:

```
import pandas as pd

jsonOutput = {"text1":"1","text2":"1","text3":"0"}

for key in jsonOutput.keys():
    jsonOutput[key] = [jsonOutput[key]]

pd.DataFrame(jsonOutput)
```

outputs:

| text1 | text2 | text3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

If the corresponding values for the keys in your json output are arrays, you don't need to iterate through the keys

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for my file (although your code works). The column with the json response is in Object formar